# How to create a empty string array and initializing?

Tags: c#

I want create an empty string array and then I set it in a loop For

```
string[] temp = new string[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            string nRoom ="R"+(i+1);
            temp[i] = c1.Reader(query,nRoom); //c1.Reader() returns a String Value                   
        }                                    // and assign "0" or "1" to temp[]
        int j = 0;
        string[] Item =new string[]{};
        for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
        {
            if (temp[i] == "0")
            {
                Item[j] = comboBox3.Text + "0" + (i + 1);
                j++;
            }  
        }
```

but i have this error :

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

in Code Line

```
Item[j] = comboBox3.Text + "0" + (i + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify array length:

```
 string[] Item =new string[4];
```

Your code initialize empty array.

Also, you can use following code:

```
var Item = new List<string>();
...
Item.Add(comboBox3.Text + "0" + (i + 1));
```

if you want dynamic length.

Comment: I know, but I want to be a dynamic array, this was an example
I want an array that  items to be added one by one without length array

Comment: he could also set it up as an empty array for example `string[] Item = { }` that will initialize it as well and allow it to grow accordingly

Comment: @MethodMan No, i tested this way but i have same error

Comment: @YuriDorokhov
after this cod i want to pass `Item`  to `comboBox4.Items.AddRange(Item);` 
but i want `object[]` how to Convert that to array ?

Comment: @Amir, `Item.ToArray()`. I suggest you rename `Item` to `item` - regarding to name conventions.

Comment: @YuriDorokhov hi,i'm sorry for this comment here .. The question for me is closed, how can I ask you a question? Could you give me your email?,please

Comment: Can you ask it in comment?

Answer (score 0):

You have created a `new string[4]` Array with size 4, your `for` loop goes to 8, so it will try to access a non-existing part of the Array. You will have to resize your Array accordingly at it's creation.

If you already know how big your Array is going to need to be, that's no problem. There are ways to [resize Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I've read somewhere that this is an expensive process. If you don't know beforehand how big your collection is going to be, using a `List<T>` might be a better option.